# Will tomatoes keep for longer if you keep the stalk in?

Tags: storage-method, vegetables, storage-lifetime, tomatoes

I know that avocados are supposed to keep longer with the stalks; I would like to know if it is also true for tomatoes?

Comment: Ripe, or green? Green'll keep for a month or more in a box at room temp. Add a ripe apple, and by the end of the month your green tomato will be ripe too. Never tried this w tomatoes on stems, a month or two being long enough for my purposes; fresh, tasty tomatoes thru November.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the stem from a tomato opens up a hole where air, moisture, and bacteria can pass through. Keeping the stem in, or somehow sealing the "scar" from the stem, will prolong shelf life.

(Published in Cook's Illustrated - requires subscription - http://www.cooksillustrated.com/howto/detail.asp?docid=1173)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, leave the stalks in.  It was by accident that I discovered this works.  I was in a rush and I picked a bunch with all the stalks attached.  By the time I got home one was knocked off.  It turns bad much faster.  So I purposely did it again, with the same results.  Once the stalk dries out, that’s when I notice the tomato starts to turn.  Sometimes I had them for a couple of weeks to my surprise.  If you would have told me, I wouldn’t have believed it.

Answer (score 1):

The tomatoes may continue ripening if you keep the stalks in.

Comment: Are you sure that the ripening rate with stalks is the different from the one without stalks?